# New to Erlang: Added an IF, vars no work?

Tags: list, variables, erlang, tuples

Anyone good at debugging Erlang? I can't figure out for the life of me what's wrong. Wherever I put the Fields variable, Erlang says that there's an error before that line...

Compile messages:

```
./eventbus.erl:6: syntax error before: FieldPositions
./eventbus.erl:24: variable 'FieldPositions' is unbound
./eventbus.erl:28: Warning: variable 'Ref' is unused
./eventbus.erl:30: Warning: variable 'List' is unused
error
```

And then the code itself.

```
-module(secret).
-export([listen/1, send/1]).

-define(TCP_OPTIONS, [binary, {packet, 0}, {active, false}, {reuseaddr, true}]).

FieldPositions = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","AA","BB","CC","DD","EE","FF","GG","HH","II","JJ","KK","LL","MM","NN","OO","PP"].


listen(Port) ->
    {ok, LSocket} = gen_tcp:listen(Port, ?TCP_OPTIONS),
    accept(LSocket).

accept(LSocket) ->
    {ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:accept(LSocket),
    spawn(fun() -> loop(Socket) end),
    accept(LSocket).    

discrim(<<>>) ->
    ok;
discrim([]) ->
    ok;
discrim(Info) ->
    EventsList = string:tokens(Info,"|"),
    process_events(EventsList, FieldPositions).

process_events([],[]) ->
    ok;
process_events([],Ref) ->
    ok;
process_events(List,[]) ->
    ok;
process_events(List,Ref) ->
    [RHead|RTail] = Ref,
    [Head|Tail] = List,
    if
    Head == [] ->
        process_events(Tail, RTail);
    true ->
        io:format("message.bus ~s ~s",[RHead,Head]),
        process_events(Tail, RTail),
        ok
    end.

loop(Socket) ->
    case gen_tcp:recv(Socket, 0) of
        {ok, Data} ->
            %gen_tcp:send(Socket, Data),
            %io:format(Data),
            discrim(Data),
            io:format("~n"),
            loop(Socket);
        {error, closed} ->
            ok
    end.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You tried to declare a value `FieldPositions` at the module level, which is not allowed in Erlang. (But you can declare functions at the module level, or declare values within functions.)

There are a number of alternatives to achieve the effect you want:

- Use a `-define` macro, much like the one in your code for `TCP_OPTIONS`.
- Inline the value of `FieldPositions` to where you wanted to use it.
- Write a constant-returning function, like: `field_positions() -> ["A","B",...,"PP"].`

As an aside, from my experience with various compilers and interpreters, I recommend you not to take the error messages too literally. In particular, I think you should treat the errors you got as "error happened *somewhere around* line x", not literally as "before line x" or "at line x".

Comment: Aha, thanks. Let me check that it works. I feel like I should have known this.

Comment: Sure, you could even create a constant-returning function like: `field_positions() -> ["A","B",...].`